# What is the meaning of getopts and IFS in shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell

I am learning shell scripting so can someone please explain with some examples on what is getopts and IFS?

Comment: You need this `http://tldp.org/guides.html`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`getopts`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#GETOPTSX) is the tool used to parse arguments passed.
[`IFS`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF)(`Internal Field Separator`) is the variable which determines how bash distinguishes words.
No offense but a simple [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+getopts) [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+IFS) would have given you the answers & samples :)
Hope this helps!